# Laravel- Paypal checkout button is not showing up

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I followed the integration tutorial of Paypal to integrate the smart payment button with my blade.html

```
    @foreach($details as $detail )
            <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between"> 
                 <h1 class="card-title">{{ $detail->project->name }}</h1>
                 <small class="text-info">assigned on {{ $detail->created_at->format('d.m.Y') }}</small>
            </div>
                          
                            <table>
                            //data fetched from database
                            </table>
                            <hr>
                            @if($detail->bid->method == 'milestone')
                            
                            @foreach($milestones as $milestone)
                            <div class="card text-white bg-dark mb-3" style="max-width: 100%;">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Milestone: {{ $milestone->name }}</h5>
                                <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                                <p class="card-text">Amount (RM) : {{ $milestone->milestoneAmount }}</p>
                                <div id="payment-checkout"></div>
                                </div>
                                 
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            @endforeach
                            @else
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Pay</a>
                            @endif
                           
                            <div class="row pt-4 float-right"><a href="{{route('projects.show',auth()->user()->id)}}" >Back</a></div>
@endforeach      

    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=Aa6YqiZeNrYj59PgmbpU6sUjOibNneCkf6QAmvNq71qVHG8BNViA6EKWBSiw-zFdGHpzWFrMR8jDDMAd"></script>
    <script>paypal.Buttons().render('#payment-checkout');</script>
```

I used the same id, payment-checkout at the div tag and also in the render() but the checkout button is not showing up. It just created a blank div space. [image]I want the button to show up at each card div.
This is the [Rendered source](https://1drv.ms/t/s!Aj5z_NtX4DAMakZF1A5W5TEYiE0)

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Obviously quite a bit of missing code there, can you add a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Hi, I have edited the question. Please have a look

Comment: Download the rendered HTML of the page from (using your browser or a command line utility) and upload that, so we can look at the actual HTML/JS that is sent to the browser (not your server code), and the actual ensuing runtime error

Answer (score 0):

> I want the button to show up at each card div.

In that case you need to call the .render() function multiple times (on each one individually), otherwise it will only render in the first match.

For simplicity each location where you want to render a button should have a unique HTML `id`.

Your main problem, though, is something else -- since the following simple sample works as expected (only one button stack will render):

```html
First:<hr />
<div id="payment-checkout"></div>
Second:<hr />
<div id="payment-checkout"></div>
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=Aa6YqiZeNrYj59PgmbpU6sUjOibNneCkf6QAmvNq71qVHG8BNViA6EKWBSiw-zFdGHpzWFrMR8jDDMAd"></script>
<script>paypal.Buttons().render('#payment-checkout');</script>
```

For advice on the main issue, update the question with HTML as served to the client (fetch using your browser or another utility), so we can look at the actual HTML/JS that is being run on the client end, and so be able to reproduce or otherwise identify the runtime error.

Comment: I added the rendered source in the question. Noticed in the first loop of foreach, it did load the paypal api i guess.

Comment: Another question is, how to call the .render() function on each individual loop though?

Comment: Your rendered source does not include the script tags with the JS, so it's useless. You should obtain the source as served by you server, before the browser executes any or the JS. The file information that your server transmitted for the page to be displayed is what is needed.